# How to get the caret from passwordfield to textarea in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm actually asking how to put the caret position from one text editable node to another. I create a password field and a textarea  in one application in javafx. When the caret is in the password field and the user entered the right password and typed KeyCode.ENTER, how can I put the caret into the textarea programmatically after the user typed KeyCode.ENTER? (not using the mouse of course...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
passwordField.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (/* check password... */ {
        textArea.requestFocus();
    }
});
```